# What happens if a RHEL activation key (by mistake) is used multiple times?

Tags: rhel

According to some [support page of Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1378093), it is possible to streamline system registration and subscription attachment of one (?or several) system(s) using activation keys.

Indeed I have a setup in which three systems have been setup and there is only a single activation key (which seems to work for all three systems each having a subscription aloted to it).

My question is with regards to find out what would happen after the activation key has been "used up" already?

Would an (even by accident) reuse of the activation key cause any harm to the systems set up?

Comment: Would not an activation key, be in violation of most of the licences of most of the software on the system?

Comment: And the last line of the paragraph on the linked page is in violation of accessability guidelines and laws (minimum contrast).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, i could be wrong on this, but it appears to be a key that activates subscriptions to some online system, not a key that activates software

Answer (score 1):

I have dared and tested to perform a registration of the system with the activation key already used. This is the result:

```
user$rhelbox$> sudo subscription-manager register --org=[ORGID] --activationkey=[activationkey]
This system is already registered. Use --force to overridefortzufahren
user$rhelbox$> echo $?
64
```

In a nutshell, luckily *there is no risk* (such as for instance accidently disabling the running system having been activated before with the activationkey)